# Extending an existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to extend an existing open source rails project (GitLab in my case) by adding/changing views (and controllers). Since the open source project is being actively developed, it would be nice if future changes can be integrated in the new product.

One could simply apply modifications directly on to the original code base. For example, I would like to perform some restyling of the project (to some extent). In this case, I could simply replace all the files in app/views with custom implementations. I could add additional param when a specific action in a controller is called by changing the original code. *However, it may become difficult to merge the latest (git) updates from the open source project your personal project.*

The primary goal is to only implement custom views (keeping behaviour of the controllers/models as-is). However, it would be awesome if the controllers/models could also be extended (in an OO manner) with fallbacks to the original code (perhaps by calling the super methods?).

*What is the best strategy to extend an existing rails project (views, controllers, models) while minimising the amount of code changes applied to the original project?*

Comment: Your question is very broad. We don't know enough about your code-base so answers will be broad-swipes, largely based on opinion.

Comment: Not mentioning what OSS project you want to do this to, nor what controllers or views you want to change mean that this question is really vague. Please add more details.

Comment: too general of a question. I would recommend looking at RailsCasts.com for specific topics, and getting familiar with Rails.